# eclipse starts up and it shows up in the task manager, but I cannot see it anywhere on the desktop

Tags: java, eclipse

When I got on Eclipse today I got an error along the lines of "Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt'." When I looked up the solution, I was told to go to /.metadata/plugins and delete the folder, which I did (I didn't delete the exact folder listed, but I deleted "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench" or something like that). After that, I was able to run Eclipse, but I immediately ran into another problem. It doesn't show up. I pinned it to the taskbar to see if it was running, but it doesn't say it is. That being said, I do see "eclipse.exe" running in the task manager, and when I try to run Eclipse again with that process running, it tells me another process of Eclipse is already running. What's going on? Why can't I see Eclipse? There seems to be a running problem with this program where one day it will work as expected and the next it suddenly stops working with no explanation (usually a day or three after install it).

Comment: Deleting things randomly very often create far more new problems than solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself by restarting the program.